# cp: silence "omitting directory" warning

Tags: bash, cp

I'm using the command `cp ./* "backup_$timestamp"` in a bash script to backup all files in directory into a backup folder in a subdirectory. This works fine, but the script keeps outputting warning messages:

```
cp: omitting directory `./backup_1364935268'
```

How do I tell cp to shut up without silencing any other warnings that I might want to know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you want to use `cp -r` in that script. That would copy the source recursively including directories. Directories will get copied and the messages will disappear.

---

If you don't want to copy directories you can do the following:

- redirect stderr to stdout using `2>&1`
- pipe the output to grep -v

```
script 2>&1 | grep -v 'omitting directory'
```

quote from grep man page:

> ```
>   -v, --invert-match
> ```

```
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

Comment: Eh, that'll work I guess. I was hoping there'd be some sort of option on cp for silencing warning messages like that but I guess not.

Comment: Do you need am recursive copy of all files and direcotories? Or only the files in the first level of `backup_$timestamp` ?

Comment: Nope, because then every time I made a backup I'd be backing up all the older backups along with other files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo :) I meant: Do you want to copy all *files* from the *first level* of the current dir to the backup folder? Maybe there is a solution using `find` without using `grep`.. This could speed up things if you have *many* files. Otherwise `grep -v` would be my preferred solution

Comment: Yeah, right now I do want to copy all the files. Perhaps in the future I may want to use the find command, but for now `./*` works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

The solution that works for me is the following:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} backup_1364935268/ \;
```

It copies all (including these starting with a dot) files from the current directory, does not touch directories and does not complain about it.

Comment: Plus one: Works in Makefile.

Comment: Note: you need a destination as the first parameter when using BSD find (e.g. Mac), so : `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} backup_1364935268/ \;`

Answer (score -2):

When copying a directory, make sure you use -R

## cp -R source source_duplicate_copy_name

-R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively

```
  --reflink[=WHEN]         control clone/CoW copies. See below
  --remove-destination     remove each existing destination file before
                             attempting to open it (contrast with --force)
  --sparse=WHEN            control creation of sparse files. See below
  --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
```